# How to move the pivot point of a GameObject without having to make a blank parent object for it to use in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made a script in unity where you can pick up objects and throw them with the mouse and they stay where they are when you first grab the object so that the mouse is offset from the center of the gameobject when its grabbed instead of snapping to the center. But when it collides with something and rotates because of the collision, it rotates around the center of the gameobject instead of rotating around the mouse. and I've been looking up how to change the pivot but all of the solutions that I have found include making an empty game object and parenting it, but the problem is that the pivot needs to change DURING runtime and with that method it can't.

I tried using removing the pivot object as parent, relocating the pivot object, then re setting the pivot Object as the parent. But it doesn't work as the pivot doesn't have a rigidbody and adding a collider wouldn't work because it would mess up the collision. as well as the grabbable object has a child and when you remove the parent, it also removes the child and I have to re add it. so I just need to change the pivot point from the script. Also I tried using RectTransform but changing the pivot didn't work either, as it still just rotates around the center.

also I am using c#, and the grabbable objects are both 2D sprites and Meshes, and to get the mouse position I am using
Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).

Comment: Can't a [`FixedJoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint2D.html) achieve that effect?